# select input by value from list with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, html-input

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
<ul id='mylist'>
    <li>
        <input val="1">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input val="2">
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I use JQuery to select an input by value?
I can get a list of li's by doing

```
$("#mylist").children('li')
```

but can't work out how to then get the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute-value](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector

The attribute to set the value to the input is `value`, not `val`

```js
$('#mylist input[value="2"]').addClass('border');
```

```css
.border {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='mylist'>
  <li>
    <input value="1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input value="2">
  </li>
</ul>
```